# Delete specific versions Android Studio VCS and/or Bitbucket

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control, bitbucket

So, I've successfully set up a Bitbucket repository and committed several versions and created several branches via Android Studio.  Now, I want to clean up the commits and branches that are no longer needed.  Also, I would like to do this through android studio and not the command line.  I can see all my versions/branches in Bitbucket and in the Android Studio Version Control window (alt-9).

I've done quite a bit of research to accomplish this seemingly easy task and come up empty.  Do I need to perform a 'delete' action in Android Studio?  in Bibucket?  Both?  How?  I could probably try to do this by trial and error, but understandably don't want to screw it up and delete necessary versions.  So, I'm looking to you for some guidance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to delete the remote branches on bitbucket firstly and then delete the local branch in android studio. Details as below:

1. Delete useless remote branches in bitbuckte. Repo in bitbucket -> Branches -> select a branch you want to delete -> click … button -> delete branch. Do the same way if you want to delete multiple branches.

[image]

2. Fetch changes from remote to android studio. Android studio -> VCS -> Git -> Fetch.
3. Delete related local branches. Android studio -> VCS -> Git -> Branches -> delete the branches both in local branches tab and remote branches tab.
   [image][image]